# how to find current event using action in oracle ADF?

Tags: oracle, events, action, oracle-adf

I need to get the event when action is getting called. I need the button id in my method bean.myAction. Please help.

```
<ce:button partialSubmit="true" action="#{bean.myAction}"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don' think this will do it for you. This method does not receive the id of the component that fires the action.
I think you need to  instead call an ActionListener method for this button - ADF will add this method to your backing bean and this method takes an argument of ActionEvent and from the event object you can get the component id that fired the event using getComponent(). You can call your action myMethod from there or add it as an Action method.